# AngularJS: PUT send data with URL but not as JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Here is my `UserService`

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/users/:userId',
      // todo: default user for now, change it
      {userId: 'bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810'},
      {update: {method: 'PUT', params:{profile: '@profile'}, isArray: false}}
  );
});
```

In my controller, I do

```
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.user.$update({profile: $scope.profile});
}
```

But when I see the Network Tab in Chrome, I see

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/users/bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810?profile=%5Bobject+Object%5D
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
```

How can I send this as `data` payload? so that `URL` is

```
http://localhost:5000/users/bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810
```

and data goes as

```
{
  day_in_month: 5
}
```

My endpoint expects the data to be part of request, so that it can parse it as `request.json`

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@lucuma answer solved my problem.

I am sharing the code from my code base which worked after making changes as per @lucuma's suggestion (Thanks a lot @lucuma!)

The `UserService` looks like

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/users/:userId',
      // todo: default user for now, change it
      {userId: 'bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810'},
      {update: {method: 'PUT', data:{}, isArray: false}} // add data instead of params
  );
});
```

and `ProfileController` looks like

```
function ProfileController($scope, User) {
    $scope.profile = {};
    $scope.user = User.get();
    $scope.save = function () {
        // I was using $scope.user.$update before which was wrong, use User.update()
        User.update($scope.profile,
            function (data) {
                $scope.user = data; // since backend send the updated user back
            });
    }
```

After making these changes, I my network tab in Chrome was as expected

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/users/bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
Request Payload:
{"day_in_month":25}
```

Comment: I had a similar frustration with .update as oppose to .$update. I think because we are using User as a service which returns $resource (instead of assigning $resource to a variable in the controller). Hopefully this comment will help anyone else trying to do this. (It certainly would have helped me!)

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you make the following change to your update declaration:

`{update: {method: 'PUT', data:{profile:'@profile'}, isArray: false}}`

Check out the network tab on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ngstqu7rQZYtahOmaJEt?p=preview).   -v.1.1.5

Here is the same example on stable [version 1.0.7](http://plnkr.co/edit/DgmEwxV7T63IPZoNdBxe?p=preview).

Comment: Thank @lucuma, I can see it works for your plunker, I tried the same thing, but not working for me, it is still getting in `URL`, I am using `v 1.0.6` for both `angular.js` and `angular-resource.js`

Comment: Here it is using the most up to date stable version (1.0.7):  http://plnkr.co/edit/DgmEwxV7T63IPZoNdBxe?p=preview  and it functions the same.

Comment: Huge Thanks @lucuma, I was doing it all wrong actually, I am adding my answer with details which will be based on what you said