# AngularJS $resource GET params appear in URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-resource

My REST backend [ based on NodeJS/express/mongojs] is complaining 404 (not found) when Params are attached as part of URL. Backend rest interface is coded as below;

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/login', auth.signin); //auth.signin is code to verify user
```

Above REST service is consumed by AngularJS based frontend through $resource as below;

Definition:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('signinmgr', function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:3000/login", {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }});
```

Usage:

```
signinmgr.get({'username':'myname', 'password':'mypass'}, function(data){
        //success 
    }, function(x){
        //failed
    });
```

**Problem:**

1. Frontend code above produces a URL to consume REST service where parameters are part of URL i.e. http://localhost:port/login?username=myname&password=mypass [if I use GET method, POST is OK]. I wanted my front end to keep URL as http://localhost:port/login and post any parameters through body as backend is using req.body.paramName to read those. [Actual Solution]
2. If (1) cannot be done, and my frontend is sending params as part of URL, I needed help as to know how to equip my backend to allow this URL with parameters so that backend doesnt return 404 as the base URL http://localhost:port/login is already there.

PS: for (1), I tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781156/angularjs-put-send-data-with-url-but-not-as-json-data) with data:{username:'',password:''} but of no use. Please help if I am missing something very obvious or some concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request that my nodejs/expressjs backend receives has three places for passed attributes;

```
params{}
query{}
body{}
```

My problem (1) cannot be fixed in case I want to use GET method since with GET request parameters are visible as part of URL i.e. http://localhost:port/login?username=myname&password=mypass. To send my username/password I had to use POST that sends parameters as part of `body{}`.

My problem (2) was that I was using GET and mistakenly looking for parameters in `body{}` of request. Instead, parameters passed as part of URL in GET request are added to `query{}` of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `$http` service instead:

```
angular.module('myapp').factor('signinmgr', function($http) {
    return {
        login: function (username, password) {
            $http.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }
    };
});

signinmgr.login('myname', 'mypass').then(function(data){
    //success 
}, function(x){
    //failed
});
```

Comment: I selected `$resource` over `$http` for some reasons that made sense a couple months back and it was working perfectl. My backend at that time was based on _restify_. I changed my backend to _express_ in current implementation and it starts complaining with `GET`. Any idea on what could be wrong with current implelementation?