# SpringMVC: The URL path calling my Method is running an Http PUT method however I receive the Error message 'Request method 'GET' not supported'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing an e-commerce website using Spring-MVC and I am in the process of creating the cart. I am looking up the URL tradingcards/rest/cart/add/P1 and receiving the error "Request method 'GET' not supported" even though the method, "addItem()" that is mapped to that URL is a PUT method.

I know that this is a lot of code to look at but i would greatly appreciate any help that is offered

CartRestController.java

```
package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Cart;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.CartItem;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Product;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.exception.CardNotFoundException;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.service.CartService;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.service.ProductService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/cart")
public class CartRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Cart create(@RequestBody Cart cart) {
        return  cartService.create(cart);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        return cartService.read(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId,   @RequestBody Cart cart) {
        cartService.update(cartId, cart);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        cartService.delete(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productID}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable String productID, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String sessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
        if(cart== null) {
            cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }

        Product product = productService.getProductById(productID);
        if(product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new CardNotFoundException(productID));
        }

        cart.addCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartService.update(sessionId, cart);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productID}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeItem(@PathVariable String productID, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String sessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
        if(cart== null) {
            cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }

        Product product = productService.getProductById(productID);
        if(product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new CardNotFoundException(productID));
        }

        cart.removeCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartService.update(sessionId, cart);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,  reason="Illegal request, please verify your payload")
    public void handleClientErrors(Exception ex) { }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal server error")
    public void handleServerErrors(Exception ex) {  }
}
```

CartItem.java

```
    package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CartItem implements Serializable{



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3285341151884777001L;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;

    public CartItem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CartItem(Product product) {
        super();
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = 1;
        this.totalPrice = product.getUnitPrice();
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        this.updateTotalPrice();
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.updateTotalPrice();
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public void updateTotalPrice() {
        totalPrice = this.product.getUnitPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(this.quantity));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 311;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((product == null) ? 0 : product.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CartItem other = (CartItem) obj;
        if (product == null) {
            if (other.product != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!product.equals(other.product))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Cart.java

```
    package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Cart implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3286257236940240478L;

    private String cartId;
    private Map<String,CartItem> cartItems;
    private BigDecimal grandTotal;

    public Cart() {
        cartItems = new HashMap<String, CartItem>();
        grandTotal = new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    public Cart(String cartId) {
        this();
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public String getCartId() {
        return cartId;
    }

    public void setCartId(String cartId) {
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public Map<String, CartItem> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(Map<String, CartItem> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public BigDecimal getGrandTotal() {
        return grandTotal;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public void addCartItem(CartItem item) {
        String productID = item.getProduct().getProductID();

        if(cartItems.containsKey(productID)) {
            CartItem existingCartItem = cartItems.get(productID);
            existingCartItem.setQuantity(existingCartItem.getQuantity()+ item.getQuantity());
            cartItems.put(productID, existingCartItem);
        } else {
            cartItems.put(productID, item);
        }
        updateGrandTotal();
    }

    public void removeCartItem(CartItem item) {
        String productID = item.getProduct().getProductID();
        cartItems.remove(productID);
        updateGrandTotal();
    }

    public void updateGrandTotal() {
        grandTotal= new BigDecimal(0);
        for(CartItem item : cartItems.values()){
            grandTotal = grandTotal.add(item.getTotalPrice());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 71;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((cartId == null) ? 0 : cartId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cart other = (Cart) obj;
        if (cartId == null) {
            if (other.cartId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cartId.equals(other.cartId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

CartRepository.java

```
    package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.repository;

import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Cart;

public interface CartRepository {
    Cart create(Cart cart);

    Cart read(String cartId);

    void update(String cartId, Cart cart);

    void delete(String cartID);
}
```

InMemoryCartRepository.java

```
package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.repository.impl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Cart;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.repository.CartRepository;

@Repository
public class InMemoryCartRepository implements CartRepository {

private Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts;


    public InMemoryCartRepository() {
        listOfCarts = new HashMap<String,Cart>();

    }


    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        if(listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cart.getCartId())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not create a cart. A cart with the give id (%) aldrady exist",cart.getCartId()));
        }

        listOfCarts.put(cart.getCartId(), cart);
        return cart;
    }


    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return listOfCarts.get(cartId);
    }

    public void update(String cartId, Cart cart) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not update cart. The cart with the give id (%) does not does not exist",cartId));
        }

        listOfCarts.put(cartId, cart);
    }


    public void delete(String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not delete cart. The cart with the give id (%) does not does not exist",cartId));
        }

        listOfCarts.remove(cartId);
    }
}
```

CartService.java

```
package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.service;

import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Cart;

public interface CartService {

    Cart create(Cart cart);

    Cart read(String cartId);

    void update(String cartId, Cart cart);

    void delete(String cartId);

    Cart validate(String cartId);
}
```

CartServiceImpl

```
package com.tradingcards.tradingcards.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.Cart;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.domain.repository.CartRepository;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.exception.InvalidCartException;
import com.tradingcards.tradingcards.service.CartService;

@Service
public class CartServiceImpl  implements CartService{

    @Autowired
    private CartRepository cartRepository;

    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        return cartRepository.create(cart);
    }

    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return cartRepository.read(cartId);
    }

    public void update(String cartId, Cart cart) {
        cartRepository.update(cartId, cart);
    }

    public void delete(String cartId) {
        cartRepository.delete(cartId);

    }

    public Cart validate(String cartId){
        Cart cart = cartRepository.read(cartId);
        if(cart==null || cart.getCartItems().size()==0){
            throw new InvalidCartException(cartId);
        }
        return cart;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

controllers.js

```
var cartApp = angular.module('cartApp', []);

cartApp.controller('cartCtrl',  function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.refreshCart = function(cartId) {
                                $http.get('/tradingcards/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function(data) {
                                                $scope.cart = data;
                                            });
                            };

    $scope.clearCart = function() {
                                $http['delete']('/tradingcards/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId)
                                     .success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));

                          };

    $scope.initCartId = function(cartId) {
                            $scope.cartId=cartId;
                            $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);
                            };

      $scope.addToCart = function(productID) {
                                $http.put('/tradingcards/rest/cart/add/'+productID).success(function(data) {
                                                $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/tradingcards/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
                                                alert("Product Successfully added to the Cart!");
                                            });
                            };
      $scope.removeFromCart = function(productID) {
                                    $http.put('/tradingcards/rest/cart/remove/'+productID).success(function(data) {
                                                $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/tradingcards/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
                                                });
                                };
      });
```

Comment: Does the client specify it is making a PUT request?

Comment: @ochi yes the client does specify it is making a PUT request. I have updated the question to include my javascript file

Comment: hmm, you seem to be missing the payload on the `PUT` request - see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/16783540/600486

Comment: @ochi i believe that it is a back-end problem not client side.

Answer (score 0):

I added this in a comment, but I am concerned (like the other commenter) about this call in your client after your put completes:

```
$http.get('/webstore/rest/cart/get/cartId')
```

I don't see a valid mapping for this call in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productID}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productID}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

I would try commenting out this call and seeing what happens.

Did you mean to call `/webstore/rest/cart/cartId`? (i.e. without the `/get`)

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean i will try changing it to that

EDIT: that made no difference. I believe that the problem is occurring before it reaches that point.